# Игнорировать шифрование диска Ubuntu, отредактировав файлы fstab и crypttab

Tags: ubuntu

Диск зашифрован. Нужно избавиться от ввода пароля. Встречал статью в интернете про Ubuntu 12.10, где описывался процесс редактирования файлов /etc/crypttab и /etc/fstab. Подскажите, как отключить шифрование, используя комментирование и запись в этих файлах?